# How do I Convert A GeoJSON List of Coordinate Pairs from Polygons to MultiPolygons?

Tags: python, gis, geojson

this is my first SO question so bare with me on it. I'll follow up with any questions you may have about the dataset.
Essentially, I'm trying to export Polygons from a GeoJSON format in Python to MultiPolygons. I'm not dealing with inner rings in this situation and instead, only dealing with separate polygons that are part of the same feature.
The first coordinate pair matches one halfway down the list which should be the closing vertex to create the full polygon. However, when I try to build the geoJSON using MultiPolygon, it's not catching the closing vertex. Do I need to create another array within my GeoJSON template? Here is what I'm dealing with below:

{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "MultiPolygon",
"coordinates": [
[
[**-79.61123945099996, 43.721808245000034**],
[-79.611124366999945, 43.721691027000077],
[-79.611111266999956, 43.721694136000053],
[-79.610997192999946, 43.721733924000034],
[-79.610645108999961, 43.720953449000035],
[-79.610625742999957, 43.720910504000074],
[-79.610741060999942, 43.720873686000061],
[-79.611097236999967, 43.720819664000032],
[-79.611695669999961, 43.720768816000032],
[-79.612286291999965, 43.720682416000045],
[-79.612399453999956, 43.720661620000044],
[-79.612447630999952, 43.720659502000046],
[-79.612449305999974, 43.720659671000078],
[-79.612518532999957, 43.720684950000077],
[-79.612550815999953, 43.720725478000077],
[-79.612667530999943, 43.721042800000077],
[-79.612668964999955, 43.721046741000066],
[-79.612714036999989, 43.721241834000068],
[-79.612751350999986, 43.72160154900007],
[-79.612755080999989, 43.721637452000039],
[-79.612829431999955, 43.722354263000057],
[-79.61287638899995, 43.722567384000058],
[-79.612971460999972, 43.722771906000048],
[-79.613108203999957, 43.722957862000044],
[-79.613008290999971, 43.723004443000036],
[-79.612832364999974, 43.722949827000036],
[-79.612752433999958, 43.722923586000036],
[-79.612715561999948, 43.722878643000058],
[-79.612640133999946, 43.722864064000078],
[-79.612008116999959, 43.722635037000032],
[-79.611981008999976, 43.722568023000065],
[-79.611852546999955, 43.722379942000032],
[-79.611754976999975, 43.722264966000068],
[-79.611650385999951, 43.722124983000072],
[-79.611588353999934, 43.722038821000069],
[-79.611438002999989, 43.721918874000039],
[-79.611354559999938, 43.721864904000029],
[**-79.61123945099996, 43.721808245000034**],
[-79.615005153999959, 43.724676721000037],
[-79.614956217999975, 43.724542822000046],
[-79.614920367999957, 43.724397802000055],
[-79.614873232999969, 43.724168390000045],
[-79.61472165899994, 43.724021132000075],
[-79.614834790999964, 43.723927020000076],
[-79.614880248999953, 43.723941177000029],
[-79.614923543999964, 43.723954029000026],
[-79.614982076999979, 43.723969650000072],
[-79.615041339999948, 43.723983777000058],
[-79.615101232999962, 43.723996394000039],
[-79.615161704999934, 43.724007486000062],
[-79.615222671999959, 43.724017047000075],
[-79.615284063999979, 43.724025060000031],
[-79.615330376999964, 43.724029862000066],
[-79.61537872699995, 43.72403419300008],
[-79.61543889699999, 43.724038243000052],
[-79.615501171999938, 43.724040768000066],
[-79.615547951999986, 43.724041441000054],
[-79.615596668999956, 43.724041465000028],
[-79.615657069999941, 43.724040169000034],
[-79.615717355999948, 43.724037181000028],
[-79.615781303999938, 43.724032256000044],
[-79.615845061999948, 43.724026136000077],
[-79.615904626999964, 43.724018758000057],
[-79.616584333999981, 43.723920345000067],
[-79.616839888999948, 43.723883298000032],
[-79.616978991999986, 43.723869196000066],
[-79.619369596999945, 43.723581859000035],
[-79.620139676999941, 43.723821041000065],
[-79.620781493999971, 43.724517952000042],
[-79.621407588999944, 43.725198202000058],
[-79.621686516999944, 43.725501395000038],
[-79.618419291999942, 43.724604442000043],
[-79.617135858999973, 43.725052291000054],
[-79.617083434999984, 43.725070585000026],
[-79.61603138199996, 43.725437648000025],
[-79.615738510999961, 43.725602405000075],
[-79.615400602999955, 43.725349885000071],
[-79.615304545999948, 43.725168104000034],
[-79.615104679999945, 43.724976768000033],
[-79.615124720999972, 43.724813159000064],
[-79.615070066999976, 43.724758973000064],
[-79.615005153999959, 43.724676721000037],
[-79.623669575999941, 43.725848943000074],
[-79.623743787999956, 43.725826005000044],
[-79.624186404999989, 43.726580879000039],
[-79.624463924999986, 43.727002028000072],
[-79.624285701999952, 43.727021382000032],
[-79.624018738999951, 43.727050384000052],
[-79.623825425999939, 43.727071382000076],
[-79.62378160999998, 43.727082755000026],
[-79.623637867999946, 43.727120036000031],
[-79.623509544999933, 43.727153312000041],
[-79.623381234999954, 43.72718659700007],
[-79.623252910999952, 43.727219873000081],
[-79.623216339999942, 43.727229355000077],
[-79.623124721999943, 43.727245596000046],
[-79.623001500999976, 43.727267443000073],
[-79.622888565999972, 43.72728451200004],
[-79.622755914999971, 43.727274527000077],
[-79.62265049399997, 43.727266586000042],
[-79.622538539999937, 43.727256308000051],
[-79.622408045999975, 43.727212105000035],
[-79.622229310999955, 43.727151564000053],
[-79.622248877999937, 43.727111707000063],
[-79.622263625999949, 43.727082670000073],
[-79.622277691999955, 43.727053454000043],
[-79.622291036999968, 43.72702405900003],
[-79.622303685999952, 43.726994503000071],
[-79.622315614999934, 43.726964794000025],
[-79.622326824999959, 43.726934933000052],
[-79.622338731999946, 43.726900814000032],
[-79.622349191999945, 43.726868388000071],
[-79.622358880999968, 43.726835838000056],
[-79.622367774999987, 43.726803171000029],
[-79.622375887999965, 43.726770388000034],
[-79.622383205999938, 43.726737516000071],
[-79.622389728999963, 43.726704555000026],
[-79.622395469999958, 43.726671513000042],
[-79.622400403999961, 43.726638401000059],
[-79.622404543999949, 43.726605235000079],
[-79.622407889999977, 43.726572025000053],
[-79.622410427999966, 43.726538771000037],
[-79.62241217199994, 43.726505491000069],
[-79.622413108999979, 43.726472203000071],
[-79.622413251999944, 43.726438898000026],
[-79.622412587999975, 43.726405602000057],
[-79.622411116999956, 43.726372317000028],
[-79.622408851999978, 43.726339059000054],
[-79.622407534999979, 43.726286784000081],
[-79.622428166999953, 43.726248370000064],
[-79.622463919999973, 43.726223299000026],
[-79.623669575999941, 43.725848943000074],
[-79.590143053999952, 43.733536012000059],
[-79.589877036999951, 43.732977982000079],
[-79.589422870999954, 43.732025230000033],
[-79.589077131999943, 43.731262783000034],
[-79.58881534599999, 43.730685459000028],
[-79.588749829999983, 43.730540974000064],
[-79.588557912999988, 43.730117728000039],
[-79.588347799999951, 43.72964554400005],
[-79.587946346999956, 43.728743347000034],
[-79.587674297999968, 43.72813194400004],
[-79.587660789999973, 43.728069386000072],
[-79.587879613999974, 43.727916815000071],
[-79.588117873999977, 43.727714109000033],
[-79.588417815999946, 43.727515856000025],
[-79.588678156999947, 43.727295130000073],
[-79.588891212999954, 43.727101443000038],
[-79.589176422999969, 43.726912201000061],
[-79.589411591999976, 43.726722997000081],
[-79.589624275999938, 43.726542810000069],
[-79.589902048999988, 43.726313067000035],
[-79.590172171999939, 43.726155338000069],
[-79.59046755899999, 43.726033593000068],
[-79.590759113999979, 43.725943355000027],
[-79.591055751999988, 43.725880114000063],
[-79.591341200999977, 43.725857388000065],
[-79.59171977699998, 43.725857087000065],
[-79.59204161599996, 43.725789320000047],
[-79.592147134999948, 43.725546204000068],
[-79.592185091999966, 43.725258135000047],
[-79.592136869999933, 43.724925133000056],
[-79.592117752999968, 43.724601109000048],
[-79.592248409999968, 43.724312968000049],
[-79.592536569999936, 43.72404270100003],
[-79.592916036999952, 43.723875873000054],
[-79.593311446999962, 43.723736034000069],
[-79.59372088899994, 43.723641188000045],
[-79.593929353999954, 43.723571058000061],
[-79.594150032999949, 43.723496817000068],
[-79.594559896999954, 43.723424469000065],
[-79.594919728999969, 43.723356663000061],
[-79.595249867999939, 43.723396893000029],
[-79.595362766999983, 43.723414801000047],
[-79.595510366999974, 43.723457334000045],
[-79.595674302999953, 43.72346404700005],
[-79.595982335999963, 43.723504293000076],
[-79.596257938999941, 43.723639079000066],
[-79.596556866999947, 43.723805347000052],
[-79.596835927999962, 43.72391762500007],
[-79.59708825499996, 43.724047928000061],
[-79.597342590999972, 43.724218733000043],
[-79.59756396399996, 43.724394066000059],
[-79.597710776999975, 43.724515456000063],
[-79.597866566999983, 43.72466834100004],
[-79.598065043999952, 43.724834693000048],
[-79.598277493999944, 43.725005532000068],
[-79.598417133999988, 43.725243944000056],
[-79.598452032999944, 43.725473444000045],
[-79.598468744999934, 43.725729964000038],
[-79.598358194999946, 43.725964090000048],
[-79.598277086999985, 43.726175688000069],
[-79.598190196999951, 43.726409793000073],
[-79.598196771999937, 43.726634817000047],
[-79.598276591999934, 43.726819274000036],
[-79.598449117999962, 43.727003650000029],
[-79.598567340999978, 43.727188073000036],
[-79.598674358999972, 43.727399509000065],
[-79.598896904999947, 43.727570340000057],
[-79.599135258999979, 43.727682648000041],
[-79.599420919999943, 43.727785916000073],
[-79.599736637999968, 43.727767638000046],
[-79.600065511999958, 43.727731344000063],
[-79.600229926999987, 43.727692672000046],
[-79.600304975999961, 43.727678686000047],
[-79.600365205999935, 43.727667461000067],
[-79.598216763999972, 43.72274630000004],
[-79.598097648999953, 43.722485370000072],
[-79.597966050999958, 43.722179443000073],
[-79.597264989999985, 43.720627347000061],
[-79.596929466999939, 43.719895898000061],
[-79.59638446799994, 43.718638844000054],
[-79.596363832999941, 43.718589355000063],
[-79.595825032999983, 43.717320649000044],
[-79.597088707999944, 43.717639119000069],
[-79.598985597999956, 43.718114546000038],
[-79.599052254999947, 43.718126553000047],
[-79.599293198999987, 43.718169302000035],
[-79.603459526999984, 43.719159182000055],
[-79.603518113999939, 43.71917263000006],
[-79.60637232199997, 43.719830926000043],
[-79.606962383999985, 43.719957027000078],
[-79.607071192999967, 43.71997996500005],
[-79.60791878699996, 43.720158646000073],
[-79.608869738999942, 43.720358138000051],
[-79.608259912999983, 43.723234053000056],
[-79.608728203999988, 43.72656680800003],
[-79.608792042999937, 43.726662336000061],
[-79.61088495599995, 43.729793959000062],
[-79.609831260999954, 43.731259124000076],
[-79.609160041999985, 43.732202352000058],
[-79.609614861999944, 43.732646676000059],
[-79.609684148999975, 43.732706076000056],
[-79.609814799999981, 43.732949215000076],
[-79.609881000999962, 43.733031614000026],
[-79.609923428999934, 43.733090720000064],
[-79.610013352999943, 43.733292708000079],
[-79.610018214999968, 43.733431083000028],
[-79.610017536999976, 43.733647063000035],
[-79.610013875999982, 43.733672502000047],
[-79.609991959999945, 43.733749015000058],
[-79.609901151999964, 43.73409821100006],
[-79.60671806199997, 43.733724609000035],
[-79.606307451999953, 43.733662760000072],
[-79.605800133999935, 43.733663232000026],
[-79.605324607999989, 43.733709654000052],
[-79.604722310999989, 43.733790677000059],
[-79.603242852999983, 43.734131228000081],
[-79.603203392999944, 43.734142349000081],
[-79.60308510699997, 43.734172131000037],
[-79.602139439999974, 43.734382274000041],
[-79.601148973999955, 43.734602324000036],
[-79.601001362999966, 43.734635118000028],
[-79.600729718999958, 43.734696826000061],
[-79.599835901999938, 43.734899865000045],
[-79.599163572999942, 43.735052578000079],
[-79.598873517999948, 43.735118109000041],
[-79.598185026999943, 43.735273653000036],
[-79.597542266999938, 43.735422168000071],
[-79.597326344999942, 43.735472057000038],
[-79.597005399999944, 43.735546211000042],
[-79.595894882999971, 43.735802788000058],
[-79.595142796999937, 43.735976543000049],
[-79.594956037999964, 43.736019689000045],
[-79.594232162999958, 43.736187912000048],
[-79.593990924999957, 43.736243972000068],
[-79.592446876999986, 43.736602771000037],
[-79.591701754999974, 43.736775955000041],
[-79.59140380499997, 43.736140678000027],
[-79.590881481999986, 43.735032664000073],
[-79.590744856999947, 43.734749703000034],
[-79.590517734999935, 43.734301714000026],
[-79.590445510999984, 43.73415946800003],
[-79.590370858999961, 43.734013858000026],
[-79.590143053999952, 43.733536012000059],
[-79.59449, 43.73129]
]
]
},
"properties": { "number": 3 }
}

In bold, you'll see the coordinate pairs that should create the closed polygon. Should Pyplt be able to detect MultiPolygons by this same pair of coordinate pairs? If not, how should I go about creating my GeoJSON to detect MultiPolygons? Below is what I'm using to create the GeoJSON loop for each feature:

```
geojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": []}

for _, row in df3.iterrows():
    feature = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [row['coordinates']]}, "properties":{"school": row['School']}}
    geojson['features'].append(feature)
```

Thanks for any help at all on this!

Comment: here's a thread on how to create polygons from points. it utilizes [gdal python bindings](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html#Contains). Also, what tells you that the last bolded coord pair is the last in the loop of coords for your polygon? whatever tells you this should be used to dynamically split the list of points so you have multiple polygons. [solution thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92754/how-can-i-group-points-to-make-polygon-via-python)

Comment: The last coordinate matches the first coordinate which should make a closed polygon. I'll see if this post helps but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, the solution to this problem would be to create a function that runs through each coordinate pair and assigns a list of polygons based on similarity between coordinate x and coordinate y where the parameter 'bag of coordinates' is our list of coordinates.

```
def coordsToMultiPolygon(bag_of_coordinates):
    polygons = [[]]
    start = None
    polygon_idx = 0
    for x,y in bag_of_coordinates:
        polygons[polygon_idx].append([float(x), float(y)])
        if start == None:
            start = (x,y)
        elif x == start[0] and y == start[1]:
            start = None
            polygons.append([])
            polygon_idx += 1
    return polygons[:-1]
```

Then just append the output to a new dictionary within your geodataframe and set the geometry column to those values.